# How to change class in button when you click on it

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, button

I have two buttons: without background and green, I need them to change when i click on them (from green to that one with dashed border-bottom) [image]

Here is my html:

```
 <div class="btns">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Муж</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-link btn-simple">Жен</button>
           </div>
```

I've written script just like this :

```
$('.btn').click(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    if ($this.hasClass('btn-success')) {
        $this.removeClass().addClass('btn-simple');
    } else if ($this.hasClass('btn-simple')) {
        $this.removeClass('btn-simple').addClass('btn-success');
       }
});
```

but it doesn't work.

and here is what I added to css file:

```
.btn-simple {
    border-bottom: 1px dashed #000;
    color: #000;
}
```

nothing else because these are bootstrap buttons.

Comment: Look at toggleClass

Answer (score 2):

you should add code in document.ready method.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('.btn').click(function () {
            var $this = $(this);
            if ($this.hasClass('btn-success')) {
                $this.removeClass().addClass('btn-simple');
            } else if ($this.hasClass('btn-simple')) {
                $this.removeClass('btn-simple').addClass('btn-success');
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the class you want to remove, for example: $this.removeClass('btn-success'). In the link below I've made an example.

```
   $('.btn').click(function(){
       var $this = $(this);
       if (!$this.hasClass('btn-success')) {
        $('.btn').removeClass('btn-success')
        $this.addClass('btn-success');

       }
    })
```

https://codepen.io/jmejia1221/pen/qMwLQP

Answer (score 1):

You were not removing one of the btn-success class. Also, I think you should add btn-link class. Also wrap this entire piece in document.ready

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.btn').click(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        if ($this.hasClass('btn-success')) {
            $this.removeClass('btn-success').addClass('btn-simple');
        } else if ($this.hasClass('btn-simple')) {
            $this.removeClass('btn-simple').addClass('btn-link').addClass('btn-success');
           }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to toggle between buttons within a shared container..

```js
/* longer version for demonstration purposes */
$('.btn').click(function() {
  var thisParent = $(this).closest('.btns');
  $(thisParent).find('.btn-success').addClass('btn-simple')
  $(thisParent).find('.btn-success').removeClass('btn-success');
  $(this).removeClass('btn-simple');
  $(this).addClass('btn-success');
})

/* shorter version
$('.btn').click(function() {
  $(this).closest('.btns').find('.btn-success').addClass('btn-simple').removeClass('btn-success');
  $(this).removeClass('btn-simple').addClass('btn-success');
})
*/
```

```css
* { outline: 0; } button { border-style: none; cursor: pointer; padding: 5px; } button::-moz-focus-inner { border: 0; }
/* ignore above */

.btn-simple {
  border-bottom: 1px dashed #000;
  color: #000;
}
.btn-success {
  background-color: hsla(96, 92%, 37%, 1);
  border-radius: 2px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="btns">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Муж</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-link btn-simple">Жен</button>
</div>
<div class="btns">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Муж</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-link btn-simple">Жен</button>
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-link btn-simple">три</button>
</div>
```

fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/Hastig/bjkchu5L/